# Find match in the backward direction from a row in dataframe

Tags: r

I have a data frame which stores a hierarchical data, a part of which is as shown below:

```
print(data)

 level           Name
   1         WRG ASM ENGINE
   2         MOUNT CLAMP
   3         Carbon Steel
   4         Carbon
   3         PA
   4         F-Fibre
```

Now say I want to find the immediate parent of row with name "Carbon". I am currently using the below code:

1.Finding the level value for Carbon,the immediate parent will have level 
   value 1 less than Carbon's.

```
    level_carbon <-data[which(data$Name=="Carbon"),"level"]
```

2.Finding position of carbon in the data frame

```
    row_num_carbon <-which(data$Name=="Carbon)
```

3.Getting index of all the possible immediate parents

```
    Parents_Carbon_index <- which(data$level==level_carbon-1 )
```

4.Index of immediate parent will be less than that of carbon and it will be 
   closest to carbon in the data frame

```
   Act_Parent_Carbon <- (which.min(Parents_Carbon_index < row_num_carbon))-1 
   Carbon_Parent <- data[Act_Parent_Carbon ,"Name"]

   print(Carbon_Parent)
   "Carbon Steel"
```

The above code serves the purpose, but I am looking for a shorter code which looks cleaner and takes less execution time.

Comment: Manish Pathak, one thing you will want to consider when you use whichever result you prefer on your data: if there's a match that has no "parent-level", then your variables might be `NA` or `NULL` or just `length()` of 0. There's nothing you can do to the code to prevent this, it'll be a property of your data.

Comment: all your processes can be summarized as `with(data,Name[(s<-which(level==level[grep("^Carbon$",Name)]-1))[s<grep("^Carbon$",Name)]])` using base R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create an identifier for order
data <- tibble::rowid_to_column(data)

# update following up @r2evans' comment: 
# below is a base R option to get rowids since rowid_to_column requires tibble
# data$rowid <- seq_len(nrow(data))

# conditions: one level up + before the given row + closest to given row
tail(data$Name[data$level == data$level[data$Name == "Carbon"] - 1 & data$rowid < data$rowid[data$Name == "Carbon"]], 1)
```

You can create a function to find the parent of a given item:

```
data$rowid <- seq_len(nrow(data)) # using base R option as @r2evans suggested

find_parent <- function(item) {
  tail(data$Name[data$level == data$level[data$Name == item] - 1 & data$rowid < data$rowid[data$Name == item]], 1)
}

find_parent("Carbon")
# [1] "Carbon Steel"
```

Comment: (1) it's, `tibble::rowid_to_column`, not dplyr; (2) could also do `dat$rowid <- seq_len(nrow(dat))` since there are no `rownames(dat)`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out!  It is easy to miss these details at late night. Just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
with(data,Name[(s<-which(level==level["Carbon"==Name]-1))[max(s<which("Carbon"==Name))]])
[1] "Carbon Steel"
```